# Intellij warning: Boolean method foo() is always inverted

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have this code:

```
private boolean changeNcheckIP() {

    //try 3 times before false
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        if(changeIP() && checkIP()) { return true; }

    }

    return false;

}
```

Intellij give me an warning at `changeNcheckIP()`:

`Boolean method changeNcheckIP() is always inverted`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a warning, not an error (you are not obligated to fix it).
IntelliJ is just notifying you that you are always using your method *changeNcheckIP()* return as inverted.
Meaning that when you are calling the method (so far in your code) you are probably doing something like:

```
if(!changeNcheckIP()) {
    //do something...
}
```

Notice the ***!*** in *if* *loop*, thats what IntelliJ is trying to tell you to "fix".
If you would use:

```
if(changeNcheckIP()) {
    //do something...
}
```

Warning will disappear (notice the removed "***!***" ), but you need to *INVERT* your return value so your *IF* logic will work properly.

Comment: The idea is, it's easier to understand when you read `if (somethingWorked())` than `if (!somethingFailed())`